# use ms access 2010 form to drill down into a table on a server

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

So I have a server and an access database. I would like to look at specific information from a table on the server, but this table has billions of records (too big for access).

Would it be possible to create a form where a user clicks on a specific name on that form and it runs a pass through query to the server to pull just those specific names? So if I click on the name "Tom" it runs a pass through query to the server and returns all records in the "name" column equal to "Tom".

Comment: You may find it handy enough to simply run a query against a linked table as long as there is an index on [specific name] : `SELECT * FROM [big table] WHERE [specific name] = Forms!aForm!aTextbox`

Comment: Yes Remou, but I am also building a user facing form for drill downs. The user will want to look at specific data, and we are building forms for them to click through with subforms. So I need to click on a form, and on the click event have it run a pass through query for that specific value that was clicked.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to run a pass-through query in a click event.

Comment: Yes, I am suggesting you use a linked table. The speed will depend on your indexes.

Comment: linked table is extremely slow, won't work. Pass through query is ~instant, takes less than 2 seconds. This is why i'm trying to get the pass through query to run in VBA

Comment: Have you ensured that you have suitable indexes?

Comment: sorry, are you suggesting i add indexes to my linked table to boost performance? I created ID's with the linked table, so access automatically makes indexes there correct? I do not have an index on the field i'm querying, so that could increase performance but i doubt at the levels i need.

Comment: Indexes on any field / column that is queried will increase performance hugely. It means that only the required data set is used and avoids a table scan. The indexes should be created in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of server? MSSQL? MySQL? Oracle?

With same VBA code it is not that difficult to get results from a MSSQL server (don't know about other DBs). Add a button to your form and add a onClick-event.

```
Private Sub btnTEST_Click()

    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Call cnn.Open("YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING")        

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = cnn.Execute("SELECT Field1 FROM BigTable WHERE Field2 = Forms!YourForm!lstboxField")

    While Not rs.EOF

        Debug.Print rs("Field1")
        rs.MoveNext

    Wend
    rs.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: In what way is this better than a linked table? Microsoft recommends DAO and linked tables since 2007. ADO is much slower.

Comment: From the little information by the original poster I assumed he tried the attach table approach. He said "too big for Access". Therefore the bypass solution.

Comment: A linked table does not use Access (Jet/ACE), so it cannot be too big for Access (RAD).

Comment: Sorry if I did not provide enough information, I think it is a MSSQL server. Also, are you suggesting I create a linked table (which i can do) then make the sql command off that table? will this run at the same speed as a pass through query?

Comment: I just ran a pass through query & a query on the exact same linked table, and the pass through query ran 10x as quick. The linked table slows down ms access.

Comment: You haven't tried the attach table approach yet? I would definitely try that first. Access uses those tables very much like local tables and is faster then my VBA snippet above. Just make sure you don't do a full table scan.